# Non-negative least-squares with random variables

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I've been working on a side project for a while that requires a huge amount of simple optimization, and have run into a pretty nasty problem while working on it. If any of you could give some advice I would really appreciate it.

**Background**

I have the three following variables:

- A known MxN matrix **A**
- A known length M column vector **b**
- An unknown length N column vector **x**.

Furthermore, in my problem they are related by the following expression:
$$Ax=b$$

In my project, I need a solution for **x** that satisfies this expression accurately as possible. By itself, this is a pretty well-studied problem! For instance, I am aware that I can multiply by the Pseudoinverse of **A** to find a good solution for **x**. However, in my problem, I also have the constraint that **x** must be non-negative. Thus, I instead am using a Non-Negative Least Squares Algorithm to solve for **x**:
$$x=NNLS(A,b)$$

So far, this solution has worked pretty well for my application!

**The Problem**

Recently, I have run into situations where every variable inside **A** is a gaussian random variable. Fortunately, I know both the mean and variance of every element in **A** with pretty high precision. In addition, **x** is entirely non-random.

Under these conditions, the problem slightly changes. I now want to find the optimal solution of **x** such that the result of the multiplication $Ax$ will have a mean value of **b** and a low variance in every element. However, I am struggling to figure out how to find the best solution for **x** with this information.

If I just use non-negative least squares to solve for this, I run into some issues. I would imagine that, if column *j* has many elements with extremely large standard deviations, the *jth* element of **x** should be very small. This is because it would not be advantageous to include noisy matrix elements when trying to generate an approximation of **b** with little variance.

However, all versions of the non-negative least squares algorithm, that I have seen, do not consider the possibility of noise or any randomness. This means that they would allow for large variance in **b** because they would only consider the mean of **A**!

**The Question**

Is there any way to make a non-negative least squares algorithm consider noise when optimizing for **x**? If not, are there alternative optimization methods I could use to solve for **x** so that the vector **b** has relatively low variance?

***Note about my background:** I've been told it is useful to responders to know the background of people who ask questions here. I'm an engineer. While I am pretty familiar with mathematics, I am not very familiar with many optimization algorithms, and do not know a massive amount about statistics.*

Comment: So basically, you want to minimize $\text{Var}(Ax)$, subject to constraints $\mathbb{E}[Ax] = b$ and $x \geq 0$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes! That's a really good way of putting it.

Comment: The problem looks like quadratic programming to me. I'd like to take some time to think about it. Are you in a hurry?

Comment: I am in no hurry. Thanks for looking at this, I've been trying to figure out this problem for weeks!

Comment: I wrote an answer explaining the details. I sometimes make mistakes, so don't trust everything I say. Also, I didn't consider the case when $\mathbb{E}[Ax] = b$ has no solution, which is possible (but not explicitly asked in your question). In this case, I assume you want to minimize something like $\text{Var}(Ax) + \lambda \|\mathbb{E}[Ax] - b\|^2$. It's a bit beyond the scope of this post. If you need help with this extension, feel free to contact me directly (see my profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned in the comments that the problem looks like quadratic programming. And indeed it is. Here are the details. (There is a lot of computation, so there might be mistakes.)

For convenience, put $y = Ax$, which is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. You are trying to minimize $\text{Var}(y_1) + \dotsb + \text{Var}(y_n)$. Let's express this objective in terms of what's known.

We have a constraint that $\mathbb{E}[Ax] = b$. The covariance matrix of $y$ is then $\Sigma = \mathbb{E}[(y - b)(y - b)^T]$, and $\text{Var}(y_1) + \dotsb + \text{Var}(y_n)$ is exactly the sum of diagonals of $\Sigma$, i.e., $\text{tr}(\Sigma)$.

Now let's simplify this even further.
\begin{align*} 
(y - b)(y - b)^T & = yy^T - b y^T - yb^T + bb^T\\
& = Axx^T A^T - b x^T A^T - Ax b^T + bb^T
\end{align*}
The covariance matrix is
\begin{align*}
\Sigma & = \mathbb{E}[(y - b)(y - b)^T]\\
& = \mathbb{E}[Axx^T A^T] - \mathbb{E}[bx^T A^T] - \mathbb{E}[Axb^T] + bb^T
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\text{tr}(\Sigma) & = \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[Axx^T A^T]) - \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[bx^T A^T]) - \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[Axb^T]) + \text{tr}(bb^T)
\end{align*}
For the first term, we use two tricks: (1) the trace commutes with expectation; (2) the trace is cyclically invariant. We get
\begin{align*}
\text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[Axx^T A^T]) & = \mathbb{E}[\text{tr}(Axx^T A^T)]\\
& = \mathbb{E}[\text{tr}(A^T A xx^T)]\\
& = \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[A^T A xx^T])\\
& = \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[A^T A] xx^T)
\end{align*}
Since you know the mean and variance of $A$, $\mathbb{E}[A^T A]$ can be computed from this information. Let's put $M = \mathbb{E}[A^T A]$. Note that $M$ is a positive semidefinite matrix of size $n \times n$. Continuing, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[Axx^T A^T]) & = \text{tr}(M xx^T)\\
& = \text{tr}(x^T M x)\\
& = x^T M x
\end{align*}
That takes care of the first term.

For the second term, put $F = \mathbb{E}[A] \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, which is known. We get
\begin{align*}
- \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[b x^T A^T]) & = - \text{tr}(b x^T F^T)\\
& = - \text{tr}(x^T F^T b)\\
& = - x^T F^T b
\end{align*}

Do the same for the third term.

So in the end, our objective $\text{Var}(y_1) + \dotsb + \text{Var}(y_n)$ simplifies to
$$ x^T M x - 2 x^T F^T b + \text{tr}(bb^T) $$
This is just a quadratic expression in $x$. Moreover, since $M$ is positive semidefinite, this is a convex quadratic expression.

The whole problem boils down to the following quadratic program:
\begin{align*}
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}} & \quad x^T M x - 2x^T F^T b + \text{tr}(bb^T)\\
\text{subject to} & \quad F x = b\\
& \quad x \geq 0,
\end{align*}
where $M = \mathbb{E}[A^T A] \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $F = \mathbb{E}[A] \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Pretty much any convex optimization package can handle it. (For example, check out [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/).)

---

Update: As fedja pointed out in the comment, the problem simplifies further. Since $Fx = b$, the term $-2x^T F^T b$ is just $-2b^T b$, which is a constant. For optimization purposes, we can drop it, as well as the last term $\text{tr}(bb^T)$ from the objective. In the end, we just have
\begin{align*}
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}} & \quad x^T M x\\
\text{subject to} & \quad F x = b\\
& \quad x \geq 0,
\end{align*}
It's still a quadratic program.

Comment: I just spent about an hour going through the derivation. First: I have learned a lot of new things about mathematics. Second: I see no mistakes. Thank you so much for answering this, you are literally a lifesaver. I might have to contact you about the additional term in the case where E[Ax] = b has no solution, but will first give it a shot myself. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @Moonbird My pleasure.

Comment: Erm... If $Fx=b$, isn't $x^TF^Tb$ just $|b|^2$ (as well as $\rm{tr}\,bb^T$), so $x^TMx$ is really the only thing to take care of? (not that it changes the complexity of the problem much though :-) )

Comment: @fedja Oh, you are right. I wasn't paying attention to the linear term. Thanks for pointing it out.